# Batch deleting folders from file.txt

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

I have a temp folder where files get loaded into and then systematically purged out.  Job to clear out files failed and now I have a number of directories/files that need to be manually deleted.  I have deletedirs.txt that contains the names of all the folders I need deleted.  I have generated the following to delete the files and folders however the path is not always the same:

```
FOR /F %%i IN (C:\dirlist.txt) DO echo y| del "C:\Temp Files\*" & rmdir /s /q "C:\Temp Files\" %%i
```

The issue is as the temp files get loaded in they form their own subfolder(s) so I have the following structure:

```
C:\Temp Files\101\folder1
C:\Temp Files\101\folder2
C:\Temp Files\103\folder4
C:\Temp Files\455\folder3
```

deletedirs.txt contains the folder names (folder1, folder2, etc.)

My script is failing because its searching for "C:\Temp Files\folder1"

How can I get the script to find 'folder1' and remove it regardless of subfolder number (101, 103, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /d  %%a IN ("c:\temp\*") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%s IN (q48890405.txt) DO (
  IF EXIST "%%a\%%s\." ECHO RD /S /Q "%%a\%%s"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the directoryname to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q48890405.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

The required RD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO RD` to `RD` to actually delete the directories.

This should assign the subdirectory names to `%%a` in turn, then for each subdirectory found, read the names from the file into `%%s`. Then see whether a directory named `%%a\%%s` exists, and delete it if it does exist.

Note that your `del "C:\Temp Files\*"` will simply delete all of the files in `"C:\Temp Files"` over and over again. It really only needs to be done once (if that's what you had intended to do).

Removing the directory disposes of all of the files it contained, provided none are protected in some way (read-only or by UAC).

Comment: Worked exactly as expected!  Thanks Magoo.